# How to set CAP_SYS_NICE capability to a Linux user?

Tags: linux, real-time

My program is using the Linux system call `setpriority()` to change the priorities of the threads it creates. It needs to set negative priorities (-10) but, as mentioned on the documentation, this fails when run as a normal user.

The user needs the `CAP_SYS_NICE` capability to be able to set the priorities as he wants, but I have no idea how to give such capability to the user.

So my question: how to set `CAP_SYS_NICE` capability to a Linux user?

Comment: Nice -10 is higher priority, but definitely nothing even remotely real-time.

Comment: It's only a pointer, so I add a comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17685265/6899

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jan Hudec is right that a process can't just give itself a capability, and a setuid wrapper is the obvious way get the capability.  Also, keep in mind that you'll need to `prctl(PR_SET_KEEPCAPS, ...)` when you drop root.  (See the `prctl` man page for details.)  Otherwise, you'll drop the capability when you transition to your non-root real user id.

If you really just want to launch user sessions with a different allowed nice level, you might see the `pam_limits` and `limits.conf` man pages, as the `pam_limits` module allows you to change the hard nice limit.  It could be a line like:

```
yourspecialusername hard nice -10
```

Comment: I know this answer is older than dirt but there is the pam_cap.so module which will read in `/etc/security/capability.conf` and set capabilities accordingly

Answer (score 22):

There is a nice handy utility for setting capabilities on a binary: *setcap*. This needs to be run as root on your application binary, but once set, can be run as a normal user. Example:

```
$ sudo setcap 'cap_sys_nice=eip' <application>
```

You can confirm what capabilities are on an application using getcap:

```
$ getcap <application>
<application> = cap_sys_nice+eip
```

I'd suggest integrating the capabilities into your makefile in the install line, which is typically run as root anyhow. Note that capabilities cannot be stored in a TAR file or any derivative package formats. If you do package your application later on, you will need a script (postinst for Debian packages) to apply the capability on deploy.

Comment: Your command works, but may I ask where you found that `cap_sys_nice=eip`, especially the `=eip` part? I can't see it neither in `man setcap`nor in `man capabilities`.

Comment: @elmicha On my system at least, the man setcap page contains the following line:
_The capabilities are specified in the form described in cap_from_text(3)_.

Note that the cap_from_text manpage may not be available by default (even if you have setcap). On CentOS for example, it's available in the libcap-devel package. It describes the extra letters as 'operator flags', where e = effective, i = inheritable and p = permitted, respectively.

Comment: What does `eip` stand for ? And can I use this for running scripts ?

Comment: @vbt, please read the bottom of the previous reply for the meaning of those letters.

You can theoretically apply capabilities on scripts, but I don't know what effect it will have. Try it if you need a capability you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK It's not possible to get a capability. Root processes have all capabilities and can give them up, but once given up, they can't be regained. So you'll need a suid-root wrapper that will give up all other capabilities and run the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access through sudo,
you can use `setpriv` to add any capability you want to a command.
Using it is a real pain in the ass, though, so I wrote a script for it.

```
#!/bin/bash

uid="$(id -u)"
gid="$(id -g)"

sudo --preserve-env \
    setpriv --reuid="$uid" --regid="$gid" --init-groups \
    --inh-caps +sys_nice --ambient-caps +sys_nice \
    "$@"
```

Save this as `/usr/local/bin/chyort` and `chmod +x` it.

To use the script, prefix the command that requires realtime permissions with `chyort`:

```
$ chyort jackd -d alsa -r 44100 -p 256
```

(The name was inspired by `chrt` and чёрт.)

Answer (score -1):

Regarding sudo, I added the user like this:

```
niceuser ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/nice
```

And then it worked fine:

```
niceuser@localhost $ nice
0
niceuser@localhost $ sudo nice -n -10 nice
-10
```

Comment: Don't do this. It runs commands as root, which is not what you would normally want, and not what the original question was looking for.