# Assigning a cpu core to a process - Linux

Tags: bash, process, cpu, affinity

Is there any way to force a process with specific PID, to be executed and run on only one of the cpu s of a server? I know that there is a command like this

```
taskset -cp <Cpu_Number> <Pid>
```

but the above command does not work on my system. So please let me know if there is any other command.

Comment: What is the server OS? A user must possess `CAP_SYS_NICE` to change the CPU affinity of a process. Any user can retrieve the affinity mask.

Comment: It is not fair to run away from the question that you just posted. Please wait for the immediate comments. Comments are often useful for clarifications in your question

Comment: Further question: Is there a way to prevent any other processes running on this core? Or is that what process affinity (this thing) already does?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are two ways of assigning cpu core/cores to a running process.

**First method:**

```
taskset -cp 0,4 9030
```

Pretty clear ! assigning cpu cores 0 and 4 to the pid 9030.

**Second Method:**

```
taskset -p 0x11 9030
```

This is a bit more complex. The hexadecimal number that follows `-p` is a bitmask. An explanation can be found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/taskset.htm), an excerpt of which is given below :

> The CPU affinity is represented as a bitmask, with the lowest order
>   bit corresponding to the first logical CPU and the highest order bit
>   corresponding to the last logical CPU. Not all CPUs may exist on a
>   given system but a mask may specify more CPUs than are present. A
>   retrieved mask will reflect only the bits that correspond to CPUs
>   physically on the system. If an invalid mask is given (i.e., one that
>   corresponds to no valid CPUs on the current system) an error is
>   returned. The masks are typically given in hexadecimal.

Still confused? Look at the image below :

[image]

I have added the binaries corresponding to the hexadecimal number and the processors are counted from left starting from zero. In the first example there is a `one` in the bitmask corresponding to the `zero`th processor, so that processor will be enabled for a process. All the processors which have `zero` to their corresponding position in the bitmask will be disabled. In fact this is the reason why it is called a mask.

Having said all these, using taskset to change the processor affinity requires that :

> A user must possess CAP_SYS_NICE to change the CPU affinity of a
>   process. Any user can retrieve the affinity mask.

Please check the [Capabalities Man Page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).

You might be interested to look at this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635515/how-to-set-cap-sys-nice-capability-to-a-linux-user) that deals with CAP_SYS_NICE.

**My Resources**

1. [Tutorials
   Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/taskset.htm)
2. [XModulo](http://xmodulo.com/run-program-process-specific-cpu-cores-linux.html)

Comment: @mahdi : May i know how you sorted it out?

Comment: Is the second method that you provided, is just another representation of the first method? Or the second method has a stronger affect on the CPU assignment?

Comment: I use the command  `ps -o pid,psr,comm -p <pid>` to see what cpu is assigned to a specific process. Then, I try to change this cpu assignment by the following command `taskset -cp <new_cpu> <pid>`. Then I again use the command  `ps -o pid,psr,comm -p <pid>`  and I see the previous cpu assignment is not changed.

Comment: `Linux divides the privileges traditionally associated with superuser into distinct units, known as capabilities, which can be independently enabled and disabled.` By default CAP_SYS_NICE is enabled for root I guess.. You can check if the  CAP_SYS_NICE is set or not by using this command `lcap -c  CAP_SYS_NICE`.