# How to duplicate a Linux device file?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, mmap, hardware-interface, memory-mapping

In our system we use `mmap()` on the `/dev/mem` file to access a memory mapped hardware device. However, using this device file requires running the application in superuser mode (`sudo`) in order to write to the physical device. We are looking for a way to get rid of this limitation.

Supposedly, one can change the access permissions on the device file. However, this is not a recommended solution.

One suggestion we had is, instead of writing a new, full kernel mode device driver for the hardware, we can duplicate the `/dev/mem` device, changing its write permission, and use `mmap()` on the new device.

Reading a few manual pages, I found the `mknod` command. So I used it to create a special file, `emem`, with similar attributes to the `/dev/mem` file (esp., the major and Minor versions of the device) . Using the new file in my program, I still needed the `duso`. So, I changed its attributes to full r/w permissions, but it did not change the need for `sudo`.

Next, I tried changing the permissions of `dev/mem` itself to 0777, but it did not help either.

Which leads to the following questions:

1. Is the need for `sudo` privilege comes from using `mmap()` or from the specific devices it maps?
2. If the former, how to eliminate this?
3. If the latter, how can I duplicate the `/dev/mem` functionality, with full permissions?

Comment: The right way to do this is to either make a kernel stub driver which allows access **only** to the specific resources needed, or to run a userspace daemon as root which proxies requests filtered with the same limitation.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - thanks. In the long term, writing a proper driver is my intention. Right now, due to lack of time (and experience in kernel mode programming), I am looking for a convenient workaround.

Comment: Duplicating the device node is pointless, since it would have all of the same issues and consequences as modifying the permissions of the existing node.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=22515

> To open /dev/mem you need both regular access permissions on the
>   device file and the security capability CAP_SYS_RAWIO, or to be root.
>   There is no getting around this, because full access to memory allows
>   a lot more than just GPIO. It has huge security implications.

This is presumably checked inside the `mem` device driver.

The solution is to give the users that need to be able to access /dev/mem the `CAP_SYS_RAWIO` capability, and also put them in the `kmem` user group (which has read access to the device).

Comment: Correct: in current kernels, the `open` call on `/dev/mem` is checked with: `return capable(CAP_SYS_RAWIO) ? 0 : -EPERM;`. See `drivers/char/mem.c`.

Comment: Thanks. so, this means that I cannot use `/dev/mem` for this purpose. Then, how can I duplicate the device driver itself, and set it to my needs?

Comment: .. wait - according to @duskwuff, if I understand correctly, this protection is assimilated in the driver code itself, right?

Comment: You could recompile your kernel with that line modified. But see my updated answer.

Comment: I am not familiar with this `CAP_SYS_*` stuff. How do you grant a user with this capability? Also, you mention the `kmem` group, which has read access to the device. My device requires read and write access. Will this work for writes as well?

Comment: Google "linux capabilities". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956732/is-it-possible-to-configure-linux-capabilities-per-user for example

Comment: By default `/dev/mem` only has group read access, you could `chmod g+w /dev/mem`. You could also try using ACLs for more fine-grained access control.

Comment: @Barmar: **THAT WILL NOT WORK.** Regardless of permissions, you cannot open `/dev/mem` unless you are root (or have the `CAP_SYS_RAWIO` capability). Please read the answer you are commenting on!

Comment: @duskwuff That's what I said in my answer: give them the capability AND give them the kmem group.

Comment: I **wrote** the answer I'm commenting on.

Comment: Derp derp derp. Anyways, the only practical way of going about this is to just be root. [CAP_SYS_RAWIO is root-equivalent already](http://lwn.net/Articles/542327/); there's really no point in trying to grant it separately from full root.

Comment: @duskwuff - the reason is that when `sudo`-ing an executable, I seem to be losing some important parts of the environment, specifically `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which I need for that executable.

Comment: @ysap: That's intentional. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is dangerous. If you need it, run: `sudo env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=... myExecutable`.

Comment: @duskwuff - yes, I know it is intentional, but adding that assignment to all executables that use that device is tiresome, and usually requires maintaining "run" scripts. We just want to get rid of that.

Comment: @ysap: So put the library on a default search path (e.g, `/usr/local/lib`) so you don't need to override it anymore?

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility, but we prefer to leave it at this place. Anyway, it will not eliminate the need for `sudo`, which is genuinely annoying when you have to do it repeatedly in order to run innocent applications. We just want to get rid of that!

Comment: Allowing LD_LIBRARY_PATH through setuid/sudo is a huge security hole, since it would allow you to replace the standard C library with a version that does whatever you want. You should encapsulate what you need inside programs, and make them setuid.