# how to grant cap_chown capability to a user in RHEL 6

Tags: linux, privileges, rhel, chown, rhel6

I want a regular user to use the `chown` command.

I followed this [procedure](http://www.sevagas.com/?Linux-security-using-a-limited) to configure **`pam_cap.so`** in `/etc/pam.c/login` and created `/etc/security/capability.conf` then I assigned the capability to the `chown` command as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956732/is-it-possible-to-configure-linux-capabilities-per-user) by sqweek.

```
# setcap cap_chown+ie /bin/chown 
# setcap -v cap_chown+ie /bin/chown 
/bin/chown: OK
```

But the user still seems to have no `cap_chown` privilege:

```
$ chown root:root nn
chown: changing ownership of `nn': Operation not permitted
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I'm facing a similar situation currently, did find out the solution?

Comment: @Phalgun No, I'm sorry.

Comment: Are you also trying to set CAP_CHOWN capability so that the s_gid bit is not cleared by chown?