# What does it means to have a capability only in the inheritable set?

Tags: c, linux, linux-capabilities

My program is being run with `cap_sys_admin,cap_setgid+i`.
Of course, I understand that they are inheritable across execve, but beside that : does they behave the same way as if I don’t have them at all since they are neither effective nor permitted?

Comment: I recognize the question is simple but the only documentation I found about this is the inheritable set can be inherited through execve. I want to known whether there’s a pratical difference between having only in capabilities in the inheritable set and not having them at all.

Comment: "My program is being run with `cap_sys_admin,cap_setgid+i`"

Do you mean you've set the inheritable permission on the file?

Comment: @sqweek No, an initial program is started as root with libminijailpreload, then such program perform a call to execve to my program. Of course, what I wonder is if it is possible to use `cap_sys_admin` without file capabilities as no writable partition is mounted without noexec *(the rootfs is on a crypto signed read only firmware)*.

Comment: @sqweek for your first sentence, this is just what the `getpcaps` command print on the screen of my process so everything is about process and not files *(also worth to mention I have no filesystems which supports xattrs)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so your process is running with some Inheritable capabilities. What does that mean for your process? Pretty much nothing. You can't call `setcap()` to make any of those capabilities Effective, since they're not in your Permitted set, and with no way to get them in your Effective set your process cannot use the capabilities itself.

However their presence in your Inheritable set may have consequences for *other* processes you launch. eg. if you were to `exec()` a binary whose file had `cap_setgid` in both its Effective and Inheritable set, that child process would start with `cap_setgid` in its Effective set.

If `cap_setgid` was *not* in your process's Inheritable set in the above example, then the fact that the file has `cap_setgid+ie` becomes irrevelant, and the child process will *not* have the stated capability.

Comment: So do ineheritable capabilities make sense only with xattr based capabilities ?

Comment: That the file's capabilities are stored as xattrs is perhaps an implementation detail, but yes the only way for an Inheritable capability to be promoted into the Permitted or Effective set is if the file is also marked with that capability.

Comment: ok sorry for insisting, so having a file which has capabilties inside it’s xattrs is the only way to use use inheritable capabilities ?

Comment: Yep. Those caps aren't going anywhere until they meet a file which also has them in its inheritable set (which is more or less what hdante's answer says).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, inherited keeps sleeping until you set the effective capabilities. As described in the manual, inherited means: "when execve, copy inherited to child inherited and permitted":

```
This is a set of capabilities preserved across an execve(2).  Inheritable capa‐
bilities remain inheritable when executing any program, and  inheritable  capa‐
bilities  are  added to the permitted set when executing a program that has the
corresponding bits set in the file inheritable set.
```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html

Comment: Pasted text is from wrong section, but correct section has the analogous idea

Comment: Yes, I read the manpage, but I don’t undersant `has the
corresponding bits set in the file inheritable set.` in the last sentence.

Comment: My question if whether there’s a pratical difference between having only in capabilities in the inheritable set and not having them at all ? If yes how they can be used.